# How to remove port number from http://localhost:8123 to use as http://localhost?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, hosts

I had to change my default apache port number 80 to 8123 (just random number)

I changed the following files ..

**httpd.conf**

```
Listen 8123
ServerName localhost:8123
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:8123
<VirtualHost *:8123>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

**Windows Hosts file**

```
127.0.0.1:8123     localhost
::1:8123           localhost
```

I am using Windows 7.

After making all these changes, I restarted apache but I am still unable to access `http://localhost` .... however `http://localhost:8123` works fine ... can someone help me find what I am doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: Adding a port number to an ip address in a `hosts` file does not makse sense. The `hosts` file is to create a relation between an ip address and one or more host names. The first entry in a `hosts` file has to be an ip address only! The follwing entries shall be host names.

Comment: If you tell a server not to listen on port xyz, it doesn't listen on port xyz, that's it.

Comment: lol is that dynmap I see?

Answer (score 5):

The only way to do this is to change back to `80`, or to install a listener on port 80 (like a proxy) that redirects all your traffic to port 8123.

When you enter a server name without a port, port 80 is assumed by default. AFAIK, there is no way to change this behaviour without changing your browser's source code.

The `hosts` file does not support the kind of redirection you are trying to do. The rules simply fail.

> **Edit:** ah, it might be possible to change the default port in some browsers. [Here's](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=281517) an article in MozillaZine for Firefox.

Comment: thanks - I'll try changing browser default port

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it with `proxyPass` and `proxyPassReverse`

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName localhost
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8123/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8123/ 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: See [this answer at serverfault](http://serverfault.com/a/80391)

Comment: Did you try with different IPs?

Comment: diff? I tried first with 127.0.0.1 and then tried http://localhost

Comment: I give up ... just going to go with port number

Comment: This looks like a good answer but it's crucial that Apache is listening on port 80 for this to work. I'm not sure whether that doesn't defeat the purpose

Comment: Best answer ever! Thanks