# How to remove :8080 from web site url using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

How to remove :8080 from web site url using .htaccess
eg.
http://web.steeplap.co.in:8080/projeqtor/view/main.php

Comment: check this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155529/how-to-remove-port-number-from-http-localhost8123-to-use-as-http-localhost

Answer (score 0):

You should change the port number to 80 in tomcat config. Port 80 is the only port which browsers hide because it's the default port.

Navigate to [your-tomcat-root]/conf/server.xml and then change

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

to

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>
```